# Is there a method to use a format (like MathML/MathJax) in C++ that can be evaluated?

Tags: c++, qt, mathjax, mathml

I am currently working on an application that graphs an equation, calculates the area beneath the curve, rotates this area, then compiles a 3D model based upon this. As of now my input equations have been "hard-coded" into the application's source code.

Example of hardcoded input:

```
double y = abs(qSin(qPow(graphXValue,graphXValue))/qPow(2, (qPow(graphXValue,graphXValue)-M_PI/2)/M_PI))
```

My question is: Is there an input format (like MathML or Math Jax) that can be used to input the math expression like:

[image]

but also have the C++ evaluate said expression.

Answer (score 0):

[LibSBML](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML) can parse MathML and other formats and produce an Abstract Syntax Tree that can be evaluated in C++. See their [ASTNode class](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/class_a_s_t_node.html) for more details.